# Merge columns into single cell

Tags: html

I create a table and what I want is to merge some cells in the last row to show the total or summary. I tried to put some CSS but it didn't work.

this the table I have.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>52</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
               <!-- merge -->

            <td></td> 
            <td></td>
            <td>Total</td>

               <!-- merge -->
            <td>102</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

what I want is to merge the first 3  in the last row

how can I do that?

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: Neither HTML nor CSS is the right technology for calculation.

Comment: to make it into a single cell..Im sorry don't know the exact word

Comment: I adjust the width but it affect also the other cells

Answer (score 3):

You could use colspan to specify which cells that you would like combined.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>52</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Total</td>
            <td>102</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be:

```
<td colspan="3"> This is Bigger! </td>
```

That is merging horizontally.

If you  want to merge vertically, you would have to say

```
<th rowspan="2"> This is also bigger, but different! </th>
```